# Python | Connecting to a remote server using sockets

Tags: python, sockets, networking

recently I've been messing around with sockets in python and i needed to connect to a remote server for a project. I know there are plenty of questions about this topic but none of the solutions worked for me and i am about to go mad if i can't get this to work.

**Server code:**

```
import socket
import threading

FORMAT = "UTF-8"
PORT = 55555
SERVER = ''
ADDR = ('0.0.0.0', PORT)

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)

def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")
    conn.send("Test".encode(FORMAT))

def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {PORT}")
    while True:
        connection, adress = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(connection, adress))
        thread.start()
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.activeCount() - 1}")

print("[STARTING] server is starting...")
start()
```

**Client Code:**

```
import socket
import threading

FORMAT = "UTF-8"
PORT = 55555
SERVER = "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx" # public ip
print(f"\nconnecting... {PORT}\n")
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)


client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    client.connect(ADDR)
except:
    print("Couldnt connect.")

print(client.recv(1024).decode(FORMAT))
```

When i change the SERVER variable in client script to my local ip (192.168.1.34), i can run these two scripts in two different pcs in the same LAN and it works well, i recieve the "Test" message in my client pc.

However, when i change the SERVER variable to my public ip and run the server in my server pc, i can't connect to the client pc. Here, my server and client pcs are NOT in the same network. Server is connected to my router whereas client is in another network. When i run the client script nothing happens and after a while i get [WINERROR 10057]

I've done port forwarding to port 55555. I tried disabling all firewalls and even creating a new rule in windows firewall to allow connections from port 55555. It still doesn't work and i can't figure out why.

If there is anyone who can see the problem here i would really appreciate it.

Comment: Possible [Carrier grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT)

Comment: It’s not the code you’ve shown if it works on your local LAN and we can’t see your firewall and port forwarding configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can see that maybe is causing a problem is in your ADDR variable. I recently did a similar project that was successful, and in my sever code I did the equivalent of:

```py
ADDR('',PORT)
```

I don't know for sure this would fix your problem, but it is my best guess from the info you provided.